# Finding something "through" the internet or "in" the internet?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I write this context:

> Dear Sir or Madam,
>
> I am XXXX from Italy.
>
> I am a Software Engineer. I have graduated from XXXX University, Faculty of XXXX, Department of XXXX on *month, day, year*.
>
> I am looking for a job in XXXX.
>
> I found your website **through** the internet.
>
> Could you please find the attached CV.
>
> I appreciate your help and efforts.
>
> Thank you very much.
>
> Yours' Sincerely,

Is it correct to use `through` ? or it would be better to use `in` ?

Thanks

Comment: `I found your website while searching a job on the Internet.` Try to re-phrase if you are in doubt. Make sure you use 'the' in front of 'Internet (capitalize it please.)

Comment: typo: while searching for a job on the Internet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use "on the internet".

[This Google Ngram shows popularity between the terms.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+internet%2Cthrough+the+internet%2Cin+the+internet&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1995&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Con%20the%20internet%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bon%20the%20Internet%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bon%20the%20internet%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOn%20the%20Internet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cthrough%20the%20internet%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthrough%20the%20Internet%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthrough%20the%20internet%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThrough%20the%20Internet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cin%20the%20internet%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20the%20Internet%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIn%20the%20Internet%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20internet%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Ste. "***Through*** the Internet" to me sounds as if you found something *"thanks to"*, *"by means of"*, not the "location" where you found something.

On top of this, and despite the fact that you don't ask for other indications about the correctness of your letter, I would eliminate the last sentence (Thank you very much) as you have already expressed your gratefulness in the line above.

I would also end the letter with ***"Yours faithfully"*** instead of ***"Yours sincerely"*** because in a CAE preparation course I was taught that the latter is used when you know the name of the person you are writing to (e.g. "Dear Mr Brown") and the former when the addressee is generic as in your example.

Comment: I've never heard that difference between _faithfully_ and _sincerely_ in this context. Interesting. Either way, though, the apostrophe needs to be omitted, as Paola has indicated.

Comment: I've never heard that either, and I'd tend to use simply "Sincerely," (no *Yours*)  I think *Yours* is too familiar and I think I am being more *sincere* than *faithful* when writing that kind of letter.

Comment: I guess it might depend on local usage. The exam I was studying for is one of the Cambridge ESOL ones, and they are quite formal and strict in their rules. In a sense, we could say that they test grammar in all the papers.